# Email em PHP não funciona

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Ele não dá erro algum, só não chega a mensagem. Enviando normalmente via um webmail vai normal, segue o formulário:

```
<form method="post" action="sendMail.php" id="formMail">
        Assunto: <input name="assunto" type="text" class="txtMail" placeholder=" O assunto do seu email aqui"/><br />
        Mensagem:<br />
  <textarea name="comment" rows="12" cols="50" placeholder=" Sua mensagem aqui"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br><br>
  </form>
```

e o codigo em PHP:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['assunto'], $_POST['mensagem'])){
        $para = "k.ozzy.r@hotmail.com";
        $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
        $msg = $_POST['message'];

        mail($para, $assunto, $msg);
    }
?>
```

Outra pergunta, existe alguma maneira de enviar pelo metodo `mail();` a mensagem de e-mail de quem esta me enviando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amigo, há um erro aqui:

```
$msg = $_POST['message'];
```

O atributo "nome" da tag  é "comment", e não "message". Deixe a variável assim:

```
$msg = $_POST['comment'];
```

Comment: Uau... obrigado pelo alerta, desculpa a imensa falta de atenção...